# Javascript: How to modify global variables within functions?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Below is the code I'm working on. I'm wondering why, when I change the variable `ttt` in the function, the changes do not stay outside of the function? I've declared it as `var ttt = new Array;` at the very top.

Also, why can't I use the variable `i` in the function?

code:

```js
  client.on('connection', function()
    {
        var sss;
        var aaa;

            console.log('Connected');

        for (i = 0 ; i < 120 ; i++)
            ttt[i] = 0;

        for (i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
        {
                client.getMatchHistory(434582, function(err, result)        
            {
                sss = JSON.stringify(result);
                var myObject = eval('(' + sss + ')');
                console.log (myObject.object.data[i].object.value);

                ttt[myObject.object.data[i].object.value]++;
            });

        }

            for (i = 0 ; i < 120 ; i++)
                console.log ("Record" + i + " Successes: " + ttt[i]);

    });
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? What do you mean when you say that the "changes do not stay outside the function?" Also, what do you mean when you ask, "Why can't I use the variable `i` in the function?"

Comment: ttt[myObject.object.data[i].object.value]++;
This line should change the ttt array. and it does -- in the function. But outside the function, later:
console.log ("Record" + i + " Successes: " + ttt[i]);
only displays as 0, no matter what.
as for i not working... in the function, the i in console.log (myObject.object.data[i].object.value); always returns as undefined and crashes. If I replace i with a number, such as 0, it works. Why can't the function reference/recognize i from for (i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, there are two separate problems with your code, and they're both somewhat related. First, `ttt` *is* being modified globally. The problem is that you're checking for the modifications before they happen. I suspect that `client.getMatchHistory()` is making an asynchronous call. There's no guarantee that all the asynchronous operations in the second `for` loop will be done executing by the time you execute the third `for` loop, where you read the array.

The second problem is one of scope, but it's not global scope that's your problem. Since `client.getMatchHistory()` is asynchronous, the callbacks will be called once the loop is done executing. Once the loop's done executing `i` will have a value of `10`. Likely this is not what you intended. You need to create a *callback generating* function, that takes the value of `i`, and returns a function that can be used as a callback. Like this:

```
function make_callback(i) {
  return function(err, result) {
    // The body of your callback in here
  };
}
```

And then you should use it like this in the body of the loop:

```
client.getMatchHistory(434582, make_callback(i))
```

This will capture the value of `i` in the current iteration and the generated callback will use that value when executed. That should fix your problem with `i`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all globals variables are effectively 'window' object fields, so you can use window.ttt to be sure you are using global variables instead of local. This code *should* work, so did you try it in developer tool? what does debugger say about presence of such variable?

As for variable i: sure, you can use it, but it better to use it locally, defining 'var i;' on the top of the function to not spoil global namespace.

Comment: It's not quite true that all variables that are effectively global are attributes of the `window` object. Variables declared with `var` before all other script includes are effectively "global" (i.e: they can be accessed and modified by all code subsequently declared/loaded), but they're definitely not attributes of the `window` object.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh That's incorrect. Even if you declare a global variable with `var`, e.g., `var my_global`, you can still access it via `window.my_global`.

Comment: @seliopou No you can't. I encourage you to check first.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I already have. I encourage you to check it for yourself, read the JavaScript semantics, and see [this work](http://www.cs.brown.edu/research/plt/dl/jssem/v1/) on desugaring JavaScript to a simplified core language that makes this fact explicit.

Comment: @seliopou It would seem you are correct. I think I've somehow gotten the wrong impression through some experiments with MozRepl - abstraction leakage of some sort.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I suspected that was the case. JavaScript dev tools frequently "break" scoping behavior, usually because they use the `with` keyword, which is almost as bad as `eval` and even less understood. No harm done.

Answer (score 0):

The `client.getMatchHistory` probably asynchronous request, you expect that after loop, you will have filled `ttt` array, to acheive this you have to make a handler which run after last loop step:

```
var afterloop=function() {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 120 ; i++)
       console.log ("Record" + i + " Successes: " + ttt[i]);
}
for (var i = 0 ; i < 120 ; i++)
        ttt[i] = 0;

var i_final=0;
for (var i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
        {   
            var i=i;   //localise i
            client.getMatchHistory(434582, function(err, result)        
            {
                i_final++;
                sss = JSON.stringify(result);
                var myObject = eval('(' + sss + ')');
                console.log (myObject.object.data[i].object.value);

                ttt[myObject.object.data[i].object.value]++;
                if (i_final>8) {afterloop();}
            });

        }
```

in  the sample, `i_final` counts done requests, they can be done in random order, due to async, so you can't refer to `i` when deciding to run  `afterloop()` , when `i_final` count to more than last executed request, you run function that should be executed after last request is done.

Note: **please use global vars as less as possible, in your code you used global `i` without any reason**

Comment: Reference errors on window. I'm not running this in a browser, but using Node.js... is that a problem?

Comment: why you need gloval var then ? add `var ttt=[];` where you invoke the function

Comment: Some really good responses. Thanks. Sifting through everything. By the way, eicto, your solution worked, I have only been programming JS for 3 days but that really helped me learn more about it.